# Apply a function to each edge in a MultiDiGraph in networkx library

Tags: pandas, networkx, apply

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if there's a way to use a function on each edge of a MultiDiGraph without resorting to a loop cycle, like what I would do with a pandas dataframe and apply() function.

One solution that comes to mind is converting the graph into a pandas dataframe and then using apply(), but this is something I would prefer to avoid, if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Interesting, the route via pandas seems like the more efficient way (if the function is vectorized/vectorizable).

Comment: I usually rely on lambda functions defined to operate on a single row incorporated within an apply().